# How do I stop list-items getting squashed whenever I hover over them?

Tags: css

I want to create a menu, where if you hover over an `<a>` it slides down by 10px, and if you unhover it slides back up 10px.

The problem is whenever you hover over an `<a>` the parent container (`<li>`) gets squashed to 0px width.

```css
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #495371;
  padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
}

.nav-list>li {
  border: 1px yellow solid;
}

.nav-list a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px red solid;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: #000;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a href="#">Stuff1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stuff22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stuff333</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>yellow: ul<br>red: a</p>
```

[JSFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/4ondtgvL/)

Comment: Do you want the li element to increase in size to accommodate the displaced a element, or do you want the displaced a element to be over the stuff beneath it (albeit by only 10px)? For the first you'll probably need to position top and for the second to do a transform translateY

Comment: the `position: absolute` in your hover class is effectively removing that element from the DOM causing the other elements to get tucked behind it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `position: absolute;` for hover effect, you'd need to use `transform: translateY();`. Also, because `a` is inherently `inline` element, you'd need to add the `transform` to its `block`-level parent of `li`.

Please see the snippet below. Very minimal change has been made to your `.nav-list li` and its `a` styles.

```css
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #495371;
  padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
}

.nav-list>li {
  border: 1px yellow solid;
  transition: transform .2s;
}

.nav-list a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px red solid;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-list li:hover {
  transform: translateY(10px);
}
.nav-list a:hover {
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a href="#">Stuff1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stuff22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stuff333</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>yellow: ul<br>red: a</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want is `position: relative;` and `top: 10px;` on your hover instead of position absolute and padding-top. This will push your element down. Note that the yellow box will not go down with it if you have it set to the anchor tag's hover. Instead, have it attach the li tag's hover event if you want both to move in that direction.

```css
.nav-list {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background-color: #495371;
  padding: 20px 20px 30px 20px;
}

.nav-list>li {
  border: 1px yellow solid;
}

.nav-list a:link,
a:visited,
a:active {
  color: #FFF;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 1px red solid;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
  color: #000;
  position: relative;
  top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-list">
      <li><a href="#">Stuff1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stuff22</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Stuff333</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
<p>yellow: ul<br>red: a</p>
```